# call C# DLL in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, wrapper, firebreath

I need to call C# DLL from JavaScript.This JavaScript page is within the Firebreath framewok.
The Flow should be
C#-->Wrapper-->Firebreath(C++)-->JavaScript.

then How to call this C# DLL or Class from JavaScript?
Please provide the solution for the same and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If DLL is a service. You only call it through JQuery ajax. Example:

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST" // Or GET
  data:"id=12&name=abc", 
  dataType:"xml", // Default type - text
  url:"/search/searchRecords", // URL of service
  success: function (data){ 
     // Do something
  }
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But We dont want to use JQuery Ajax,please provide me another solution.